# The problem with the code is that the code run once only for i=0 .It is not repeating for next index.Why?

Tags: python, instagram, instapy

The problem with the code is that the code run once only for i=0 .It is not repeating for next index.Why?

````
list1=['shukla928','kavita_patel7']
list2=['7379561059','kavitapatel9ptl']

for i in range(0,1):
    session=InstaPy(username=list1[i],password=list2[i],headless_browser=True)
    session.login()

    session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled=True, max_followers=500)


    session.set_do_follow(enabled=True, percentage=100, times=2)
    session.follow_by_list(followlist=['pankaj_patel63'], times=2, sleep_delay=60, interact=False)
    # session.end()```
````

Comment: There is no next index. `range(0, 1)` is equivalent to `[0]`.

Comment: `for i in range(0,1)` will run only for i=0 by default. If you want to run for i=1 change it to `for i in range(0,2)`

Comment: Replacing range(0, 1) to range(0, 2) makes more sense.

Comment: It's often nicer to iterate directly over the list elements instead of the indices. Here you could do `for username, password in zip(list1, list2)` (and probably rename your lists to be something like `usernames` and `passwords`).

Answer (score 1):

`range(i,j)` implies run from `i` to `j-1`.

So, `range(0,1)` implies run from `0` to `0` so it runs just once.

You could use `range(0,len(list1))` if both lists have same lengths.